# Importing array as arguments in a chained javascript function

Tags: javascript, chaining

I know about `call` and `apply` in javascript and are able to apply them to simple functions, but I get completely confused when it comes to applying them to a chained method call as the one shown below:

```
db.collection("posts").find({}, {limit:10, sort:[['views', -1]]}).toArray(function(err, posts) {
   console.log(posts)
});
```

Is it possible to pass the arguments from an array, something like `[{}, {limit:10, sort:[['views', -1]]} ]` into the above method using `call` or `apply` ?

I would like to use this to easily access & modify the arguments by keeping them in an external array.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to keep the chaining. You'll need to store the intermediate result.

```
var posts = db.collection("posts");
posts
    .find.apply(posts, argsarray)
    .toArray(function(err, posts) {
        console.log(posts)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, these are equal in functionality:

```
obj.func(1, 2, 3);
obj.func.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]);
```

With this in mind, you can do the following:

```
db.collection("posts").find.apply(
  db.collection("posts")
  [ {}, {limit:10, sort:[['views', -1]]} ]
).toArray(...);
```

Of course, this is pretty inefficient, since you would be calling the collection twice. So you could do:

```
var collection = db.collection("posts");
collection.find.apply(
  collection
  [ {}, {limit:10, sort:[['views', -1]]} ]
).toArray(...);
```